# Chai assertions doesnt seems to be working within my JS and Webdriverio Framework / method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, chai, webdriver-io

Currently im using an object modelling approach to replicate pages and initialising the chai libraries within the wdio file however my method seems to be failing, any ideas?

Method:

```
confirmSuccessfulSubmission() {
    const successfulSubmissionHeader = $('#contact_reply h1');
    console.log("TEST2: " + successfulSubmissionHeader);
    console.log("TEST2: " + successfulSubmissionHeader.getText());
    successfulSubmissionHeader.should.equal('Thank You for your Message!');
    // successfulSubmissionHeader.waitForDisplayed(3000);
    // expect(successfulSubmissionHeader).to.equal('Thank You for your Message!');
}
```

Output of test execution:

```
2019-02-21T21:14:16.752Z INFO wdio-cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2019-02-21T21:14:20.660Z INFO wdio-local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg:
[0-0] TEST2: [object Object]
[0-0] TEST2: Thank You for your Message!
2019-02-21T21:14:30.098Z DEBUG wdio-local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
2019-02-21T21:14:30.106Z INFO wdio-cli:Launcher: Run onComplete hook
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these lines:

```
 console.log("TEST2: " + successfulSubmissionHeader);
 console.log("TEST2: " + successfulSubmissionHeader.getText());
```

returning this output:

```
[0-0] TEST2: [object Object]
[0-0] TEST2: Thank You for your Message!
```

It look like in this line:

`successfulSubmissionHeader.should.equal('Thank You for your Message!');`

you are comparing the object successfulSubmissionHeader to the string 'Thank You for your Message!', I don't think that's what you meant to do.

Use

`expect(successfulSubmissionHeader.getText()).to.equal('Thank You for your Message!');`

to compare the text of the element to the string instead.